# Merge multiple streams join in Flink

Tags: java, apache-flink

I have three different streams coming from different sources (**Objects:** `Trade,MarketData, WeightAdj` , the only thing they have common is 'product'. Here is my streams.

**Trade stream:** tradeid, product, executions

**MarketData stream:** product, marketData

**Computestream:** product, factor

What I want to achieve using `Flink` I want to join all three streams and produce latest value of `Tuple3<Trade,MarketData,WeightAdj >`. Which means every time if any of these stream emit an event I should get latest of `Tuple3<Trade,MarketData,WeightAdj>`

I tried joining these streams using 'connect' function followed by `keyBy` but it is not producing Enriched object if MarketData or WeightAdj events are emit.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
// some code 
  tradeStream.connect(marketStream)
    .keyBy(
            new KeySelector<Trade, String>() {
                @Override
                public String getKey(Trade trd) throws Exception {
                    return trd.product;
                }
            }, new KeySelector<MarketData, String>() {
                @Override
                public String getKey(MarketData marketData)
                        throws Exception {
                    return marketData.product;
                }
            }

    )
    .flatMap(new JoinRichCoFlatMapFunction())
    .connect(weightStream)
    .keyBy(new KeySelector<Tuple2<Trade, MarketData>, String>() {
        @Override
        public String getKey(Tuple2<Trade, MarketData> trd) throws Exception {
            return trd.f0.product;
        }
    }, new KeySelector<WeightAdj, String>() {
        @Override
        public String getKey(WeightAdj wght) throws Exception {
            return wght.product;
        }
    })      
    .flatMap(new TupleWeightJionRichCoFlatMapFunction())
    .print();
}

public static final class JoinRichCoFlatMapFunction extends RichCoFlatMapFunction<Trade, MarketData, Tuple2<Trade, MarketData>>{

    private ValueState<Trade> trades;
    private ValueState<MarketData> marketData;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration config) {
        trades = getRuntimeContext().getState(new ValueStateDescriptor<>("Trades", Trade.class));
        marketData = getRuntimeContext().getState(new ValueStateDescriptor<>("MarketData", MarketData.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void flatMap1(Trade trd,Collector<Tuple2<Trade, MarketData>> out) throws Exception {

        MarketData mktData = marketData.value();
        if (mktData != null) {
            marketData.clear();
            out.collect(new Tuple2<Trade, MarketData>(trd, mktData));
        } else {
            trades.update(trd);;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void flatMap2(MarketData mktData,Collector<Tuple2<Trade, MarketData>> out) throws Exception {

        Trade trd = trades.value();
        if (trd != null) {
            trades.clear();
            out.collect(new Tuple2<Trade, MarketData>(trd, mktData));
        } else {
            marketData.update(mktData);;
        }
    }
}

public static final class TupleWeightJionRichCoFlatMapFunction extends RichCoFlatMapFunction<Tuple2<Trade, MarketData>, WeightAdj, Tuple3<Trade, MarketData, WeightAdj>>{

    private ValueState<Tuple2<Trade, MarketData>> tradeMarketState;
    private ValueState<WeightAdj> weightState;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration config) {

        TypeInformation<Tuple2<Trade, MarketData>> info = TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<Tuple2<Trade, MarketData>>(){});
        tradeMarketState = getRuntimeContext().getState(new ValueStateDescriptor<>("Trades", info));
        weightState = getRuntimeContext().getState(new ValueStateDescriptor<>("Weights", WeightAdj.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void flatMap1(Tuple2<Trade, MarketData> trdWithMaktData, Collector<Tuple3<Trade, MarketData, WeightAdj>> out)
            throws Exception {

        WeightAdj weigt = weightState.value();
        if (weigt != null) {
            weightState.clear();
            out.collect(new Tuple3<Trade, MarketData, WeightAdj>(trdWithMaktData.f0, trdWithMaktData.f1, weigt));
        } else {
            tradeMarketState.update(trdWithMaktData);;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void flatMap2(WeightAdj weightData,Collector<Tuple3<Trade, MarketData, WeightAdj>> out) throws Exception {

        Tuple2<Trade, MarketData> trdWithMktData = tradeMarketState.value();
        if (trdWithMktData != null) {
            tradeMarketState.clear();
            out.collect(new Tuple3<Trade, MarketData, WeightAdj>(trdWithMktData.f0, trdWithMktData.f1, weightData));
        } else {
            weightState.update(weightData);;
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are just using relational algebra, I'd recommend to use [Table api](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/tableApi.html). If you want to stick to DataStream API, why not using the [join](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/dev/stream/operators/joining.html) with global windows? Note that if you have unbounded input, your state will eventually explode.

Comment: Yeah, that makes more sense. Any example would be helpful using Table api because I tried that also but not getting what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your goals correctly, there are a couple of points that need to be handled differently:

- Don't call `clear()` on any of the state, because you need to continue to remember the last value you've seen from each of the three streams.
- Always call `out.collect()`. If `flatmap1` or `flatmap2` is being called, that means that something has been updated, so there's something new to report out.

(It looks like you are mimicking the logic used in the [RidesAndFares exercise](https://training.ververica.com/exercises/rideEnrichment-flatmap.html) from the Flink training. In that exercise the requirements are different: in that case there is a pair of Ride and Fare events that need to be combined, on a one-time basis. After finding a Ride/Fare pair for a given rideId, the join is done for that rideId.)

And now a couple of caveats:

- If you never call `clear()` and if the product space is unbounded, then you'll be keeping an ever-increasing amount of state indefinitely. If this is an issue, you can use [state TTL](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/state.html#state-time-to-live-ttl) to arrange for stale state to be cleared.
- Keep in mind that the Tuple serializer can't handle nulls if it is used with RocksDB. I would be tempted to rewrite each of your flatmap methods along these lines:

```java
public void flatMap1(Trade trd, Collector<Tuple2<Trade, MarketData>> out) throws Exception {

    trades.update(trd);;
    MarketData mktData = marketData.value();
    out.collect(new Tuple2<Trade, MarketData>(trd, mktData));
}
```

but when the application starts, this may produce a `Tuple2` where `mktData` is null. So it would be a good idea to protect against that.

As Arvid mentioned, the Table/SQL API makes these kinds of joins easy.